# Linking.addEventListener not working in react native

Tags: react-native, ios-universal-links, react-native-linking

I have successfully implemented a universal link that opens up a specific page in my app (if the app is turned off).  The problem is that if the app is running in the background, the eventListener is not being called.  Here is the code:

```
import {Linking} from 'react-native';
export default class App extends React.Component {

    async componentDidMount(){
        Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
        let url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
        if (url) {
            console.log('MOUNT GET INIT URL','initial url  ' + url);
        }
    }
    _handleOpenURL = (event) => {
        console.log("in _handleOpenURL", event.url)
    }
}
```

`MOUNT GET INIT URL` is successfully logged to the console.  `in _handleOpenURL` is never logged.  It seems other people on the internet have had this problem but no one has answered it.  Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Did you adjust info plist file to specify what files your app can handle ?

Comment: Do you mean adding applinks:<domain> to capabilities?  If so, then yes. If not, then no.

Comment: did you found any solution on this? I have the exact same problem

Comment: @DanutPralea i just posted the answer

Comment: yeah, that's funny. I resolved it the same way. I didn't thought on posting the answer though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this just before the last `@end` in appdelegate.m:

```
// iOS 9.x or newer


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```

Comment: Just adding that it is necessary to `#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>` on the start of the file.

Comment: Implemented this but addEventListener still not working. Am I possibly misting something subtle ?